# R computing the sum of a series

Tags: r

Lets say I have a column of numbers such as below:

```
Y=
1
2
3
4
5
6
34
32
23
```

I have an array `R1 = (1,3,7,8)`

I would like to achieve adding the elements of Y by making use of subscripts defined in R1.
I need to generate an array of values like : The sum of numbers starting from Y[1] to Y[3] as my first element, sum of numbers starting from Y[3] to Y[7] as my 2nd element, sum from Y[7] to Y[8] as my third element and so on.

Comment: Please look up how `dput` works - it will help you provide us with code to reproduce your example data.

Answer (score 5):

The `embed` function is useful for constructing the sort of offset series that are needed here:

```
embed(R1,2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    1
[2,]    7    3
[3,]    8    7
# So this becomes a simple one-liner:
 apply(embed(R1, 2) , 1, function(x) sum(Y[x[2]:x[1]]) )
#[1]  6 52 66
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, though I'm sure there are better ways.

First, explode your `r1` into a vector of the indices we want to sum over:

```
idx <- sapply(seq_len(length(r1) - 1), 
              function(ind, x) seq(x[ind], x[ind+1], by = 1),
              x = r1)
```

which gives us a list whose components are the vectors of indices for the summations:

```
> idx
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7

[[3]]
[1] 7 8
```

Once we have this, it is easy to `sapply()` over that (well, we `sapply()` over the indices `seq_along(idx)` as we need to reference more than one vector in the anonymous function) and sum the elements of `y` indexed by `idx[[1]]`, by `idx[[2]]` etc.:

```
sums <- sapply(seq_along(idx),
               function(ind, y, idx) sum(y[idx[[ind]]]), 
               y = y, idx = idx)
```

Which results in

```
> sums
[1]  6 52 66
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
> startend <- cbind (head (R1, -1), tail (R1, -1))
> startend
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    3    7
[3,]    7    8
> apply (startend, 1, function (i) sum (Y [i [1] : i [2]]))
[1]  6 52 66
```

Comment: Thank u everyone for the kind response.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to the answer from @cbeleites (I worked through a similar answer first, which took a couple minutes), but avoids creating the `startend` object:

```
sapply(seq_along(R1[-1]), function(x) {
  sum(Y[do.call(":", as.list(R1[x + c(0, 1)]))])
})

# [1]  6 52 66
```

**EDIT:**

OK, you don't need the `do.call` bit. I was bored.

```
sapply(seq_along(R1[-1]), function(x) {
  sum(Y[R1[x] : R1[x + 1]])
})

# [1]  6 52 66
```