# How to sum over range and calculate a series in R?

Tags: r, sum

Here is the formula which I am trying to calculate in R.

[image]

So far, this is my approach using a simplified example

```
t  <- seq(1, 2, 0.1)
expk <- function(k){exp(-2*pi*1i*t*k)}

set.seed(123)
dat <- ts(rnorm(100), start = c(1994,3), frequency = 12)
arfit <- ar(dat, order = 4, aic = FALSE)  # represent \phi in the formula

tmp1 <- numeric(4)  

for (i in seq_along(arfit$ar)){
    ek <- expk(i)
    arphi  <- arfit$ar[i]
    tmp1[i] <-  ek * arphi
    }

tmp2 <- sum(tmp1)

denom = abs(1-tmp2)^2
s2 <- t/denom
```

Error : Warning message:
In tmp1[i] <- ek * arphi :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I was trying to avoid using for loop and tried using sapply as in solutions to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296918/r-computing-the-sum-of-a-series).

```
denom2 <- abs(1- sapply(seq_along(arfit$ar), function(x)sum(arfit$ar[x]*expf(x))))^2
```

but doesnt seem to be correct. The problem is to do the sum of the series(over index k) when it is taking values from another vector as well, in this case, t which is in the numerator. 
 Any solutions ?

Any suggestion for a test dataset, maybe using 0 and 1 to check if the calculation is done correctly in this loop here ?

Comment: Are you sure you mean `rep(4, NA)`? That throws an error since you can't repeat something `NA` times. Perhaps you want `rep(NA, 4)`?

Comment: Your given code has a few more things that prevent it from working ... For instance, `tmp1` is a vector and so is `exp1`. You can't replace a single element of a vector with a vector, so `tmp1[i] <- exp1 * arphi` throws an error. You may want to `rm(list=ls())` and make sure your code works.

Comment: I have renamed the variables to make them clearer. Actually that is the problem which I am not able to resolve and forces me to rethink the logic of the code. Its giving the error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".

Comment: In addition to the issue Will pointed out, `arfit` is length 0.  Have you examined `arfit`?  Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes. Set `i=1` and run the lines of the loop individually in sequence. Notice that `tmp[i]` is an atom and `ek * arphi` is a vector. You cannot assign a vector to an atom of another vector, only values, so you get an error.

Comment: Sorry for not verifying that. When I ran this code, I used another dataset from astsa and when posting, used this time series for example sake.

Comment: @Frank Indeed. The line `arfit <- ar(dat, order = 4)` should actually be `arfit <- ar(dat, order = 4, aic=FALSE)` to prevent that issue by forcing there to be four terms. Also, the loop should be `for (i in seq_along(arfit$ar))` so the loop doesn't ever try to reference `[0]` of a vector.

Comment: Thanks for reminder to use for(i in seq_along(x)) but that doesnt resolve the error.

Comment: Perhaps you mean for your function to be: `expk <- function(k){sum(exp(-2*pi*1i*t*k))}` as in your equation? That would make `ek` an atom.

Comment: Thanks.That seems to work. Wondering what test data(In terms of simple 0's and 1's) to use to check if its calculating as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60352/discussion-between-anusha-and-will-beason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing up the answer determined in chat. Here's a solution involving `vapply`.

First correct `expk` to:

```
expk <- function(k){sum(exp(-2*pi*1i*t*k))}
```

Then you can create this function and `vapply` it:

```
myFun <- function(i) return(expk(i) * arfit$ar[i])
tmp2 <- sum(vapply(seq_along(arfit$ar), myFun, complex(1)))
```